# How to use Angular 4 project developed in Visual Studio 2015 to Angular 6 using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular6

I am working with Angular 4 project with web API using Visual Studio 2015 update 3. It is an ERP solution project.

Now I want to update my angular 4 project solution to angular 6 (by using Visual Studio Code).

I don't know how to change my project solution to angular 6 (or how to take the code of Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio Code).

I am new to Angular. I searched everywhere but I could not get the actual solution.

Comment: @akhilmirali if i understand your problem you want to update you angular project 4 to 6?

Comment: @Abhishek you are right.I want to update you angular project 4 to 6 by using vs code

Comment: follow this (https://update.angular.io/)

Answer (score 2):

Do not worry, VS code is a file-based and project-independent editor. It means easily you can just use "**[open folder](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-setup-angular-development-environment-in-visual-studio-code/)**" menu to set workspace on your project folder and so on.

Even they added [Multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) which you can enjoy it to handle more than one project at the one instance of VS code.

Answer (score 1):

Vs code is just another editor, like the atom, sublime or Web Strome. It has nothing to do with updating the angular version. Check angulars official guides on how to update angular they have made updating really easy. Click the link to visit the guides.
https://update.angular.io/